# jooq startup: command line to generate classes

Tags: java, classpath, jooq

could you help me to change this command line to use it in a MacOS? the jar files will **be on the desktop**.

> java -classpath jooq-2.0.0.jar;jooq-meta-2.0.0.jar;jooq-codegen-2.0.0.jar;mysql-connector-java-5.1.18-bin.jar;. org.jooq.util.GenerationTool /guestbook.xml

Thank you.
F.

---

### UPDATE:

ok, this is the full lines and the error that I got. All the listed jars are present in the folder:

java -classpath ~/Desktop/JOOQ/jooq-2.1.0.jar:~/Desktop/JOOQ/jooq- 
meta-2.1.0.jar:~/Desktop/JOOQ/jooq-codegen-2.1.0.jar:~/Desktop/JOOQ/ 
mysql-connector-java-5.1.15-bin.jar:. org.jooq.util.GenerationTool /bookstore.xml

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jooq/ 
util/GenerationTool 
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: 
org.jooq.util.GenerationTool 
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202) 
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) 
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190) 
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306) 
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301) 
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)

---

### UPDATE 2

If I change the path removing ~/ and usign:

java -classpath /Users/fabio/Desktop/JOOQ/jooq-2.1.0.jar:/Users/fabio/Desktop/JOOQ/jooq-meta-2.1.0.jar:/Users/fabio/Desktop/JOOQ/jooq-codegen-2.1.0.jar:/Users/fabio/Desktop/JOOQ/mysql-connector-java-5.1.15-bin.jar org.jooq.util.GenerationTool /Users/fabio/Desktop/JOOQ/bookstore.xml

I got a different error:

Apr 1, 2012 5:19:52 PM org.jooq.tools.JooqLogger error
SEVERE: Cannot find /Users/fabio/Desktop/JOOQ/bookstore.xml
Apr 1, 2012 5:19:52 PM org.jooq.tools.JooqLogger error
SEVERE: -----------
Apr 1, 2012 5:19:52 PM org.jooq.tools.JooqLogger error
SEVERE: Please be sure it is located on the classpath and qualified as a classpath location.
Apr 1, 2012 5:19:52 PM org.jooq.tools.JooqLogger error
SEVERE: If it is located at the current working directory, try adding a '/' to the path
Apr 1, 2012 5:19:52 PM org.jooq.tools.JooqLogger error
SEVERE: Usage : GenerationTool

Comment: Really strange. I assume that the redundant spaces are a display artifact. For me the command seems to work with only the jooq-2.1.0.jar and jooq-codegen-2.1.0.jar in the classpath. Can you try and remove all other jars (and especially that :. at the end)?

Comment: I'm sorry, doesn't work. Maybe should I type other Terminal commands before?

Answer (score 3):

You can prepend the full path to each jar file (e.g. ~/Desktop/), and you also need to replace the windows classpath separator (semicolon, ';'), with the UNIX/MAC separator (colon, ':'). For example:

```
java -classpath ~/Desktop/jooq-2.0.0.jar:~/Desktop/jooq-meta-2.0.0.jar:~/Desktop/jooq-codegen-2.0.0.jar:~/Desktop/mysql-connector-java-5.1.18-bin.jar:. org.jooq.util.GenerationTool /guestbook.xml
```

Comment: ok, I tried putting the files in ~/Desktop/JOOQ folder... and I got a class not found exception:

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jooq/util/GenerationTool
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jooq.util.GenerationTool

Comment: The command above assumes the files are directly under Desktop (not in a JOOQ folder). You basically just need to specify the full path to each of the jar, and separate them by colon (:). The same command works fine for me. If it still fails please profile the exact command you're using and a listing of the files in the relevant directory.

Answer (score 1):

Ok found. Commands to use:

1. cd /Users/fabio/Desktop/JOOQ
2. java -classpath /Users/fabio/Desktop/JOOQ/jooq-2.1.0.jar:/Users/fabio/Desktop/JOOQ/jooq-meta-2.1.0.jar:/Users/fabio/Desktop/JOOQ/jooq-codegen-2.1.0.jar:/Users/fabio/Desktop/JOOQ/mysql-connector-java-5.1.15-bin.jar:. org.jooq.util.GenerationTool /bookstore.xml

The ':.' after the last jar file is required.

Thank you.